# Node pg library auto commit vs explicit commit

Tags: node.js, postgresql, node-postgres

I am using Node pg to connect and use my Postgres Database. I use Postgres functions from node js to insert update or fetch data. I also use connection pooling to get connections to the DB.

1. When using node PG let us say I fire an insert query, do I need to
   call Commit or is this an auto commit.
2. Also if I call some function from node which do some modification to
   the data do I need to explicitly call commit.
3. I was wondering if the library allows me to do something better than
   calling commit on every call.
4. Note that this is not about complex transactions with intermediate
   save points or anything but the basic full commit.

Comment: Your question is confusing. First, you say that you are using functions from Node JS, and then you are asking about a possible `COMMIT`, which is irrelevant in such context. If you use a transaction inside a PG function, then you must control the transaction inside the same function. And if you initiate a transaction from Node JS, by using `BEGIN`, then you need to finalize it with either `ROLLBACK` or `COMMIT`. Outside of transactions nothing needs to be done in addition to executing simple queries.

Answer (score 0):

Postgres database is different from the Oracle or SQL server database in that the default mode for the database itself is Auto commit, i.e. if there is no Begin statement before you execute an DML Statement - Insert Update delete then the statement just commits on completion of execution. If you need better transaction control then we have to explicit start with a "Begin" which then would require the "Commit" or "Rollback" there by giving better control. So the answer to the above question is if you dont start with a begin statement then there is no need to worry about calling commit. –  Vivek Anand Y 6 hours ago

Comment: Neither Oracle no SQL Server require a `COMMIT` outside a transaction.

Comment: @vitaly-t Seems like your comment was wrong at that time. See [node.js oracledb Does Not Insert nor Update](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33782924/11154841) which says "the default on node-oracle is false". The downvotes of this question were probably not right, I upvoted the downvoted Q/A since it helped me finding out that "commit" is not the issue when trying to update postgres with node.js.