# node.js oracledb Does Not Insert nor Update

Tags: node.js, oracle

node-oracledb version 1.2
node v0.12.7

Selects work as expected.
For Updates and Inserts, Though we get rowsAffected: 1, the insert or Update is not effected.

```
var oracledb = require('oracledb');
```

oracledb.getConnection(
    {
        user: "HRTest",
        password: "********",
        connectString: "localhost/XE"
    },
    function (err, connection) {
        if (err) {
            console.error(err.message);
            return;
        }
        connection.execute(
            "UPDATE  TBCUSTOMERDetails set FIRSTNAME=:fn  WHERE id=:id ",
            {fn: 'new name', id: 1},

function (err, result) {
            if (err) {
                console.error(err.message);
                return;
            }
            console.log(result);

            connection.release(
                function (err) {
                    if (err) {
                        console.error(err.message);
                        throw(err);

                    }
                    else console.log("released connection");
                }); // end release
        }); // end function


});</code></pre>

Comment: I know nothing about node.js, but you may be missing a commit.

Comment: node-oracledb 1.2?  It's time to upgrade. The current node-oracledb release is 1.13.1.  And node is up to 8.1.4.

Answer (score 17):

Thanks daivrz, committing fixed the issue, the default on node-oracle is false.

```
var oracledb = require('oracledb');
oracledb.autoCommit = true;
```

Comment: Avoid setting that flag globally, since over-committing impacts performance and can may not satisfy your transactional requirements.  You can set on each `execute()`.

Comment: yes this did the magic, but beware every query will commit the oracle transaction queue and any rollback will not be possible, so if possible do with callback after bindings...

Comment: You're a lifesaver. Thanks :)

Comment: It's curious that "oracledb.autoCommit = true" didn't work for me (oracledb lib version 5.1), at least using connection pool; but passing "autoCommit: true" in the options object, when calling execute, worked like expected.

Answer (score 2):

The native settings for the oracledb driver set the autoCommit to false. You can either set the autoCommit to true at the beggining of the script or call it in the connection.execute() callback.

```
connection.execute(
            "UPDATE TBCUSTOMERDetails set FIRSTNAME=:fn  WHERE id=:id ",
            {fn: 'new name', id: 1},
        {autoCommit: true},
        function (err, result) {
            if (err) {
                console.error(err.message);
                return;
            }
            console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue with oracledb 4.0.0, and managed to resolve using **async/await**, however you may use the promise alternative:

```
const oracledb = require('oracledb');

const dbConfig = {
    user: "USER",
    password: "123456",
    connectString: 'ip:1521/dbname'
};

async function run() {
    let connection;

    try {
        connection = await oracledb.getConnection(dbConfig);

        const query = "UPDATE OCCASION SET State=:state, Title=:title WHERE Id=:id";



        const result = await connection.execute(query, {
            state: 2,
            title: 'new title',
            id: 238
        }, { autoCommit: true});

        console.log(result);


    } catch (err) {
        console.error(err);
    } finally {
        if (connection) {
            try {
                await connection.close();
            } catch (err) {
                console.error(err);
            }
        }
    }
}

run();
```

If you don't want to immediately commit after an `execute()`, you can use an [explicit commit()](https://github.com/oracle/node-oracledb/blob/master/doc/api.md#-424-connectioncommit) at any desired time later. Note that this requires a 'roundtrip' to the database server unlike the autoCommit options which are 'piggybacked' onto the execute() call.

```
promise = connection.commit()
```

### CAUTION:

According to the [docs](https://github.com/oracle/node-oracledb/blob/master/doc/api.md#commit), when it comes to `executeMany()`, there is an optional parameter named `batchErrors` (default is false), and it can affect `autoCommit`.

When `batchErrors` option is set to true, it allows invalid data records to be rejected while still letting valid data be processed during INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE and MERGE operations. In this case,  all valid data records will be processed and a transaction will be started but not committed, even if autoCommit is true. In such conditions, the application can examine the errors, take action, and explicitly commit or rollback as desired.
As expected, when `batchErrors` option is false, the executeMany() call will stop when the first error occurs.